# Rails undefined method 'full_name'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

I have this error, when I'am testing my controller

```
ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `full_name' for nil:NilClass
```

My tests:

```
class PostsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
include Devise::TestHelpers

setup do
    @post = Post.create!(title: "my title", content: "bla bla bla")
    user = User.create!(email: "example@mail.com", first_name: "name", last_name: "surename",
                    password: "password", password_confirmation: "password")
    sign_in user
end

test "should show post" do
    get :show, id: @post
    assert_response :success
end
```

full_name method in model:

```
def full_name
  "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
end
```

and my view:

```
Wrote by
  = @post.user.full_name
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Hey think thier is no user for your current post thats why it's returning this exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your requirement, each post must be associate with user so you must belongs_to association in post model. something like:

```
belongs_to :user
```

And in User model, like:

```
has_many :posts
```

Then your code should like:

```
setup do
  user = User.create!(email: "example@mail.com", 
         first_name: "name", last_name: "surename", 
         password: "password", password_confirmation: "password")
  @post = user.posts.create!(title: "my title", content: "bla bla bla")
  sign_in user
end
```

Comment: I had associations, but i changed the setup code on yours, and it works. Thank you!